# What is the difference in meaning between “fellowship” in 1 Corinthians 1:9 & “communion” in 2 Corinthians 13:14?

Tags: greek, word-study, 1-corinthians, 2-corinthians, pneumatology

What is the difference in meaning between “fellowship” in 1 Corinthians 1:9 & “communion” in 2 Corinthians 13:14?

1 Corinthians 1:9

> <sup>9</sup> God is faithful, by whom ye were called unto the **fellowship** of his Son Jesus Christ our Lord. <sup>KJV, ©1769</sup>
>
> <sup>Θʹ</sup> πιστὸς ὁ θεὸς δι᾽ οὗ ἐκλήθητε εἰς **κοινωνίαν** τοῦ υἱοῦ αὐτοῦ Ἰησοῦ Χριστοῦ τοῦ κυρίου ἡμῶν <sup>TR, 1550</sup>

2 Corinthians 13:14

> <sup>14</sup> The grace of the Lord Jesus Christ, and the love of God, and the **communion** of the Holy Ghost, be with you all. Amen. <sup>KJV, ©1769</sup>
>
> <sup>ΙΔʹ</sup> Ἡ χάρις τοῦ Κυρίου Ἰησοῦ Χριστοῦ καὶ ἡ ἀγάπη τοῦ Θεοῦ καὶ ἡ **κοινωνία** τοῦ Ἁγίου Πνεύματος μετὰ πάντων ὑμῶν ἀμήν. <sup>TR, 1550</sup>

The interlinear bible shows that the [1 Corinthians 1:9](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/1_corinthians/1-9.htm) &  [2 Corinthians 13:14](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/2_corinthians/13-14.htm) has the same Greek word [koinónia](https://biblehub.com/greek/2842.htm)

So why are two different words used in King James Version (ed. 1769)? Is there any real difference?

Also, what is the meaning of these words? What happens in and during fellowship or communion? What are the benefits of fellowship or communion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, I notice that Robert Young has translated both occasions of the Greek word as 'fellowship'.

It was the chosen decision of the translators of the KJV to vary the words they used in translation to avoid repetition.

They also attempted to express the same Greek words differently in English where they felt the context (in English) would require a different English word. To some extent this can be justified as words have a spectrum of meaning and the English spectrum of one word may not exactly match the Greek spectrum of a Greek word.

But ideally a single word should be found (if possible) to translate a single word.

'Communion' implies a union. 'Fellowship implies a 'fellow'.

I think I can see why the translators, in 1611, have used two different words.

In speaking of Jesus Christ, they have used the word 'fellowship' of him who is regarded in some scriptures as a 'brother' or a 'fellow-heir' and who came 'in the likeness of sinful flesh' and who is seen as a 'surety' (the original means 'one who draws near').

In speaking of the Holy Spirit, they have used the word 'communion' of him who is united in a spiritual union, in regeneration. The Holy Spirit, that Divine Person, is given by the Father and unites with the spirit of the believing soul in a unity. Hence the translators have chosen to express this as 'communion'.

It seems to me, therefore, that the use of the two words reflects the reverence of the KJV translators towards the Person of Jesus Christ and they are emphasizing his humanity in union with his Deity when they say 'fellowship'.

And I think that they are emphasizing the spirituality of the Person of the Holy Spirit in using the word 'communion'.

Comment: Thank you so much brother @NigelJ :-)

Comment: You are most welcome, brother @Siju.

Comment: That's a really good explanation. Where Greek only had one word, but context would have held different meanings for that audience, we translate it into different words in English since we have them at out disposal.

Comment: Thank you @Jesseיִשַׁי. On re-visiting this question I am unable to forget that the OP who posed the question passed away from Covid last year, in his home country of India, at the age of 42. How short is our time in this passing phase of our existence !

Comment: Wow. Stuff is starting to get real.

Comment: @NigelJ I'd like to have a place we can properly chat if we ever need. You have insight on various things, but we really don't have a proper place in comments. I made a chat room if you want. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136783

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, the Greek word for **fellowship** should be **υποτροφία**.

**κοινωνίαν** is communion ([Strong's 2842](https://biblehub.com/greek/2842.htm))

They do not have the same definition, which is vital for the content of Scripture. So this could be a mistake by translators that they decide to translate the same word differently when they don't need to. They may have been the same concept to the Greek audience.

Comment: Hi, David. Glad to have you on Hermeneutics! Make sure you closely watch the [tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour). Your answer doesn't really address the issue of the same word translated two ways. It's the Greek that is the same word, English uses two different words. It wasn't translated into Greek, but to English from Greek. Your answer makes it seem that it was translated *into* Greek. So, I edited your answer, to clear that up; I hope this agrees with your point. Could you cite your research with a link? Or, could you state which Bible passage uses *υποτροφία*?

Comment: Though I edited this to help out a new user, I can't agree with this answer because **υποτροφία** doesn't show up in the Bible. It may be used outside the Bible, but currently it seems that *within the Bible*, **κοινωνίαν** is the only word available for both **communion** and **fellowship** for that Greek audience.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the difference comes from religious or traditional connotation of those words particularly for the communion of the Holy Spirit (what exactly is the connotation, should be asked in the Christianity.SE). The English translations mainly follow the Latin Vulgate: fellowship comes from *societatem* in [1Cor1:9](https://studybible.info/compare/1%20Corinthians%201:9), and communion comes from communication (Douay-Rheims, translation from Latin), *communicatio*: Latin, in [1Cor 13:14](https://studybible.info/compare/2%20Corinthians%2013:14). You can search the etymology of these words for more details. There must be a ritualistic reason behind the development of this synonym. The words mean the same thing, concerning sharing commonly. Thayer lexicon states: κοινωνία, κοινωνίας, ἡ (κοινωνός), fellowship, association, community, communion, joint participation, contact; in the N. T. as in classical Greek.

1858 Sawyer, 1Cor 1:9

> God is faithful by whom you are called into the **society** of his Son Jesus Christ our Lord.